# Disable caching in `less +F` (make live output not wait for newline)

Tags: less, putty

In `less` command there is a handy feature - live tail which is enabled via Shift+f when viewing a file.

However it has a built-in caching - it doesn't output anything until it meets a newline symbol. Thus when your script outputs something like "1 2 3 4 5..." without newlines then `less` won't display it in real-time.

Is that possible to avoid this caching? Maybe with another command which does the same?

**Upd.**
More details about my case. I'm connecting to Ubuntu server over SSH via Putty. And when I'm using `less` live tail then it outputs data only when it either fills whole screen width or contains a newline. Maybe it's not `less` caching but Putty instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your experience in PuTTY matches mine in iTerm2 (Mac), so I don't think it's your client.

If you don't need the interactive features of `less`, you could try `tail -f` -- this seems to handle the lack of new lines better.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct answer because it actually solves the announced issue. However this way is far from ideal. When I run it in a virtual machine then it alerts `tail: cannot determine location of 'file.log'. reverting to polling: Input/output error`. On a real ubuntu server works fine. However it's not that convenient as `less` because it simply outputs everything into terminal. In `less` you can hit `Ctrl+c` and then quit back into terminal without wasting it. Anyway thanks

Comment: Maybe you need `tail -F` or `tailf` if the file is being turned rotated beneath your feet?

Comment: `tail -F` outputs same error but multiple times :) well it's not such big deal to waste time for this. I'm fine with `tail -f` on my ubuntu server. At least it allows to see real time progress without waiting for newline.